# Poincare's Theorem (Inclusion-Exclusion Principle)

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

> "A lottery consists of 100 tickets, labeled 1,2,3,4,...100, three of
> which are "winning numbers". You buy 4 tickets. Calculate the
> probability, p, that you have at least one winning ticket. Try
> deriving the solution via Poincare's theorem"

Poincare's Theorem is given by:
$ Pr(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_{i})= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1}S_{i} $

where $S_{j}=\sum_{i_{1}<....<i_{j}}Pr(A_{i1}\cap A_{i2}...\cap A_{ij})$

So $A_{i}$ = {you purchase a winning ticket} ;  $i=1,2,3$

How would you apply Poincare's Theorem here? I've never used it before on an actual example.
I only know the theory but I would like to know how it works on a example.

Applying normal combinatorics I get approximately $0.1164$ as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event "at least one winning ticket" is a union of four events:
exactly $i$ winning tickets, where $i$ varies between $1$ and $4$.
The exclusion-inclusion principle (which you call "Poincare's theorem") then can be used to calculate the probability of the union as follows:
The probability to win exactly one ticket minus the probability to win exactly two tickets plus the probability to win exactly three tickets minus the probability to win exactly four tickets. I'm sure you can do the calculation.

Answer (score -1):

As 3 of the 100 winning tickets, we will have C100,3= 161,700 different ways for the lottery to list the possible 3 winning tickets, remembering that the order of the 3 tickets is not relevant, since 3, 2, 1 is equivalent to 1, 2, 3. As the bettor chooses 4 of the 100 tickets in order to verify the possible hits, we define the events A1 , A2, A3 and A4 as follows:

A1= {first ticket of the 4 tickets chosen by the bettor},

A2= {hit the second ticket out of the 4 chosen by the bettor},

A3= {hit the third ticket out of the 4 chosen by the bettor} and

A4= {hit the fourth ticket out of the 4 chosen by the bettor},

So by the inclusion-exclusion principle theorem we get:

S1= #Ω= C100,3= 161700

-S2= -(#A1+#A2+#A3+#A4)= -C4,1 * C99,2 = -4 * 4851= -19404

S3= #A1∩A2+#A1∩A3+#A1∩A4+#A2∩A3+#A2∩A4+#A3∩A4= C4,2 * C98,1= 6 * 98= 588

-S4= -(#A1∩A2∩A3+#A1∩A2∩A4+#A1∩A3∩A4+#A2∩A3∩A4)= -C4,3 * C97,0= -4 * 1= -4 in this way we get :

#Ω \ (A1∪A2∪A3∪A4)= S1-S2+S3-S4= 161700-19404+588-4= 142880 possibilities for the bettor not to hit any winning ticket out of the 4 chosen.

Therefore, the probability of the bettor hitting at least 1 winning ticket is:

P= 1- P(hit zero winning ticket), that is, P= 1-(142880/161700)=~ **0.11638** as we wanted to demonstrate.

Or, if we wanted to compute

#A1∪A2∪A3∪A4= S2-S3+S4= 19404-588+4= 18820, so the probability of the bettor hitting at least 1 winning ticket is given by:

P(A1∪A2∪A3∪A4)= (18820/161700)=~ **0.11638**

It is evident that using the knowledge of the hypergeometric distribution we would arrive at the answer quickly, being

P(X= 0)= (C4.0 * C96.3)/C100.3 we would therefore obtain P(X>= 1)= 1-P(X= 0)=~ **0.11638**.

Comment: At this forum, the language we use is English.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.